# Invalid Characters error in LateX question marks all over the document

Tags: errors

The power energy was shut down while I was working and when I opened my file there were lots of question mark. My whole work is in here and lost it! What do I do?

**Attempt:**

I've tried to delete .aux file and nothing has changed. Here is **part** of my log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.8.17)  19 DEC 2016 14:26
entering extended mode
**"./Contas e DÃºvidas.tex"
("Contas e DÃºvidas.tex"
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 ï
     ¿½ï¿½  \ï¿½  q  uï¿½  ï¿½2  tï¿½  ï¿½.  sï¿½  ï¿½ï¿½  2ï¿½  ï¿½3  aï¿½...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no ï in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ¿ in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ½ in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ï in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ¿ in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ½ in font nullfont!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ï¿½ï¿½ 
            \ï¿½  q  uï¿½  ï¿½2  tï¿½  ï¿½.  sï¿½  ï¿½ï¿½  2ï¿½  ï¿½3  aï¿½...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ï¿½ï¿½  
            \ï¿½  q  uï¿½  ï¿½2  tï¿½  ï¿½.  sï¿½  ï¿½ï¿½  2ï¿½  ï¿½3  aï¿½...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ï¿½ï¿½  \ï
              ¿½  q  uï¿½  ï¿½2  tï¿½  ï¿½.  sï¿½  ï¿½ï¿½  2ï¿½  ï¿½3  aï¿½...
```

My input file:

```
 ��
```

Comment: Really? I can't believe this! I don't have a backup... I don't know what do to.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's right. When I open in TexMaker it only appears question marks everywhere. How should change this enconding?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I change to UFT-32 I get a bunch of chinese characters.

Comment: beware randomly changing encodings in an editor, depending on the meaning of the command in the editor you might be _editing_ (irreversibly corrupting)   the file data.

Comment: Note that if your file data has been changed to be a string of replacement characters that can not be reversed you need to go back to the version of the file before that replacement was done.  reversing it would be like recovering the original text after you had changed every letter to `x`, it simply is not possible.

Comment: So I lost all my work?

Comment: I know nothing of texmaker, but most editors store at least one backup `~` or `.bak` or some such as you edit.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly your output consists of terminal output showing `ï¿½`  assuming a latin1 (not UTF) terminal encoding that represents the three bytes

```
EF BF BD
```

which are the three bytes of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding of the character U+FFFD which is `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` ie the character a Unicode system substitutes when it is confused and can not decode the input.

pdftex would not have done this, however your editing software might have, if it was given latin 1 (iso-8859-1) encoded data but told to read it as UTF-8.

You need to show some of your input file.

Comment: I had a user today (texstudio, win10) where his file was all of a sudden all null bytes. Just to be safe we made a copy. We tested in various editors even "type" in the dos prompt all null byes. But when we opened the file in "WordPad" it actually found the file (which was immediately saved to a new file). We did some more tests. The original and the copy from earlier has the same SHA1 signature. But WordPad can only get data on the original not the copy. I do not understand Windows file systems.